# Yarn install causes an error: '401 Unauthorized'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

When trying to run yarn install, I am getting:

```
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
error Error: http://-----------.int:8080/tfs/-------/_packaging/Node-Packages/npm/registry/@dnd-kit/sortable/-/sortable-7.0.2.tgz: Request failed "401 Unauthorized"
```

I looked it up and found a lot of information online. The first was to update my npmrc with a new token (Azure). I did this, but it didn't change anything. Here is my .npmrc:

```
engine-strict = true
registry=https://---------------.int/tfs/--------/_packaging/Node-Packages/npm/registry/               
always-auth=true
strict-ssl=false

; begin auth token
//--------.int/tfs/------/_packaging/Node-Packages/npm/registry/:username=--------
//---------.int/tfs/-------/_packaging/Node-Packages/npm/registry/:_password= {Base64 encoded token}
//sourcecontrol.sandhills.int/tfs/--------/_packaging/Node-Packages/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
//--------.int/tfs/---------/_packaging/Node-Packages/npm/:username=-----------
//---------.int/tfs/--------/_packaging/Node-Packages/npm/:_password= {Base64 encoded token}
//----------.int/tfs/---------/_packaging/Node-Packages/npm/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
; end auth token
```

I have tried clearing yarn's cache. I have tried deleting and reinstalling yarn. One thing to note is that nobody else that is working on this is running into this problem, even though they have the same .npmrc. I also compared my yarn config list with someone else's and theirs is identical to mine. I am not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: Not sure how security-minded this is but have you tried with someone else's token? Could be that you don't have the right permissions (which should have lead to a 403 but sometimes you see a 401 anyway).

Comment: @chill389cc I don't completely understand how it is all set up, but we all share a token.

Answer (score 2):

After spending a day trying everything, I found a fix by deleting my yarn lock file and then running yarn install.